# Issue with reading the data, class org.dom4j.Document, ContentType: application/atom+xml;charset=utf-8;type=feed. at

Tags: java, talend

I'm having an issue with tRestClient,

I'm getting this error

Exception in component tRESTClient_2 (STG_Projet1)
javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: Problem with reading the data, class org.dom4j.Document, ContentType: application/atom+xml;charset=utf-8;type=feed.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.reportMessageHandlerProblem(ResponseImpl.java:439)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.doReadEntity(ResponseImpl.java:379)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.readBody(AbstractClient.java:524)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.handleResponse(WebClient.java:1129)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doResponse(WebClient.java:1117)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doChainedInvocation(WebClient.java:1042)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:895)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.invoke(WebClient.java:426)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.get(WebClient.java:609)
    at projet_ap._project1_0_1.Project1.Process(STG_Projet1.java:14486)
[ERROR]: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils - Problem with reading the data, class org.dom4j.Document, ContentType: application/atom+xml;charset=utf-8;type=feed.

[image]

this job was working fine.

Sould it be a data quality problem ?

Thx

Comment: Could you try with tREST instead of tRESTClient ?

Comment: I tested tREST  and it is not consuming my XML, it seems that tRestClient became unable to read XML content when I change the **"Accepted type "** from **xml** to **All** it reads well but tXMLInput can't parse it. this job was running without any problem I didn't upgraded any version !

Answer (score 0):

I got this from another [site](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d2045398/logiciels/solutions-d-entreprise/business-intelligence/talend/protocole-rest-erreur-lors-reponse/):

This answer suggests to use advanced settings, and add a HTTP header
"content-type" "text/plain"
thus:
[HTTP Header in tRest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bziz3.jpg)

And this worked for me.